# what does `.rodata.str1.8` section mean in elf file

Tags: gcc, elf

I know the `.rodata` section stores constant data in an ELF file. However, when I dump an ELF of a kernel module, I notice that there are two extra sections named `rodata.str1.8` and `rodata.str1.1`. It seems that these two sections store constant variables and strings as well. But what exactly are the differences between these three `rodata`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `.rodata.str1.1` has strings without alignment requirements, while `.rodata.str1.8` must be 8-byte aligned. If you look at an ELF file with `readelf` this is visible:

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00000000 000034 000050 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 2] .rela.text        RELA            00000000 000184 000030 0c   I  8   1  4
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS        00000000 000084 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 4] .bss              NOBITS          00000000 000084 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 5] .rodata.str1.8    PROGBITS        00000000 000088 000010 01 AMS  0   0  8   <---
  [ 6] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 000098 000019 01  MS  0   0  1
  [ 7] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0001b4 000049 00      0   0  1
  [ 8] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 0000b4 0000a0 10      9   7  4
  [ 9] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 000154 00002f 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
```