# Why is there more than one .rodata section being mapped to the LOAD segment, yet only one .rodata output section is specified in the linker script?

Tags: linux, gnu, elf, linker-scripts

Here is my linker script :

```
ENTRY(__startup)
SECTIONS
{
   . = 0x0000;
   .text : { *(.text) }
   . = . + 0x4000;
   .rodata : 
   { 
     *(.rodata) 
     *(.rodata.*) 
   }
   .bss : { *(.bss) }
   .data : { *(.data) }
}
```

Simple Enough. However, when all of the object files get linked together and I look at the segment mapping for the executable I get the following:

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x0
There are 6 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000034 0xfffff034 0xfffff034 0x000c0 0x000c0 R   0x4
  LOAD           0x000000 0xfffff000 0xfffff000 0x000f4 0x000f4 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x01a18 0x01a18 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x002a18 0x00005a18 0x00005a18 0x00038 0x00038 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x002a50 0x00005a50 0x00005a50 0x0010c 0x0010c RW  0x1000
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     
   02     .text 
   03     .rodata .rodata 
   04     .bss .bss .data 
   05
```

Doing an objdump on the program also shows two .rodata sections. The system I'm running on is ubuntu 16.0.4 and my compiler is gcc (I'm using LD, the GNU linker).

Does anyone know the reason why two output sections of the same name would be generated by the compilation? And is there a way to force it to one? It's entirely possible that this is more than just a generic question about the command language script, but as I can't show the codebase I'm working with, I still thought it wouldn't hurt to ask the good people on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Have you looked to see if they are actually duplicated in the resulting ELF? Is this causing you an issue? Something tells me this code was built with position independent code as well. That might not work too well if you are doing freestanding code. May I inquire what this ELF file will be used for? I asked because of the fixed offsets at the bottom of memory. I suspect it is intended to be loaded onto some device? i'd be curious what the output of `objdump -x` shows on the executable file. PS:

Comment: Usually you place BSS after data do that the BSS section doesn't take up space in the final executable. Maybe this is design intent in this case, just an observation.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Your assumption is correct. The ELF file is being loaded onto a device being developed in-house. I believe I have identified the reason in my answer below, which was causing the mismatch between the compiler and the source code that was expecting one .rodata section. Thank you for your input. I will certainly bring up the BSS in the next meeting and see if that is design intent or not.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the default behavior of the LD linker is to allocate different .rodata sections based on whatever alignment is required for the constants that are being stored in read-only memory. For more information refer to here:

[what does `.rodata.str1.8` section mean in elf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47323981/what-does-rodata-str1-8-section-mean-in-elf-file)

Comment: You can set alignment of the input sections that make up an output section by using the `SUBALIGN` option. As an experiment does this alter things `.rodata : SUBALIGN(4)`  instead of `.rodata :` . SUBALIGN(4) would align each input section that matches the rules under it and align to a 32-bit boundary (4 could have been a any value that is a power of 2).There isn't anything wrong with different alignment for subsections, just making an observation about something that may change the behaviour if you ever wanted to change it.