# How do I force .rodata.strX.Y sections to be linked as one singular .rodata section?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, ld, elf

I am currently dealing with code injection, and it has some very specific constraints.
Namely, I need one single `.rodata` section, that **has** to be named `.rodata`.

Problem is, when compiling my C++ code, my string are put into a `.rodata.str1.1` section instead.

So, I refered to [Why is there more than one .rodata section being mapped to the LOAD segment, yet only one .rodata output section is specified in the linker script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897140/why-is-there-more-than-one-rodata-section-being-mapped-to-the-load-segment-yet), which explains that this is due to alignment of these sections: one `.rodata` is created for each alignment configuration.

But, while it does tell us why this happens, it doesn't say how to fix it and make all alignments the same to merge into one single `.rodata` section (neither does [the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47323981/what-does-rodata-str1-8-section-mean-in-elf-file) linked in the answer of that question).

So I'd basically want to make the alignment the all of my .rodata sections the same, and then merge them into one single `.rodata` section. All of this using the linker script or by passing arguments to the linker or compiler. The internet hasn't helped me much on this, I guess this is quite of a unique issue.

There is a comment in one of the posts that mentions using `SUBALIGN` and/or `ALIGN` in the linker script, but those didn't work.

Thanks in advance!